# How do I get my user picture back?

Tags: users

Apparently if you take the "minimal" installation, it does not create the user picture field. I tried to manually create it, but now the Simple Facebook Connect module is not synching profile images, because it can't find the default user_picture field.

This is what the facebook module does:

```
// Try to download the profile picture and add it to user fields.
if (user_picture_enabled() && $picture_url) {
  if ($file = $this->downloadProfilePic($picture_url, $fbid)) {
    $fields['user_picture'] = $file->id();
  }
}
$new_user = User::create($fields);
$new_user->save();
```

I can confirm that it is able to get the $file, but the problem has something to do with the fields.

How do I correct recreate the "user_picture" field?

This is returning false:

```
function user_picture_enabled() {
      $field_definitions = \Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldDefinitions('user', 'user');
      return isset($field_definitions['user_picture']);
}
```

How do I add this field definition again?

I looked in the minimal.install file. I was hoping to find the code that enables user_picture, but all I could find was:

```
\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('system.theme.global')->set('features.node_user_picture', FALSE)->save(TRUE);
```

There is nothing in standard.install. I tried running the following, without any luck.

```
\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('system.theme.global')->set('features.node_user_picture', TRUE)->save(TRUE);
```

How do I get my user_picture field back without adding it manually, since I would end up with field_user_picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User pictures are no longer guaranteed to exist in Drupal 8. It is added by the standard profile, but not added if you use the minimal profile.

```
$field = \Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig::loadByName('user', 'user', 'user_picture');
$default_image = $field->getSetting('default_image');
$file = \Drupal::entityManager()->loadEntityByUuid('file', $default_image['uuid']);
$file->getFileUri();
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I get it BACK if it was removed? The facebook connect plugin wants the field to be "user_picture". If I add a field manually, it becomes "field_user_picture". So how do I get "user_picture" back?

Comment: You need to do it in the way that the original install profile does it, through config. Look at /core/profiles/standard/config/install/field.field.user.user.user_picture.yml

Comment: Importing the user picture related config files from the standard profile worked for me.